# Resetting form in VueJs Form Generator

Tags: vue.js, form-generator

I have a dynamic form using VueJs form generator, using simple button like textBox or text area I update an array of model and array of schema, and use it like this,

```
var fromControlRules = new Vue({
    el: '#form',
    components: {
        "vue-form-generator": VueFormGenerator.component
    },
    data() {
        return {
            model: {
                model: formModel (//array of model)
            },
            schema: {
                fields: formSchema (//array of schema)
            },
            formOptions: {
                validateAfterLoad: true,
                validateAfterChanged: true
            }
        }
    },
```

'formSchema' is like this,

```
formSchema = [
{
  type: "input",
    inputType: "text",
    label: "Name of the field",
    model: "name"
},
{
    type: "input",
    inputType: "text",
    label: "Type of the field",
    model: "type"
}];
```

On submit or cancel of the modal form, I want to clear the model, but doesn't happen when I see the form the fields are still there.
Let me know how I can reset the form, so probably I can create a new form, this time maybe with date fields and dropdowns instead of text boxes.

Comment: How do you clear the model?

Comment: Since it is reactive in nature, I tried formSchema = []; but that didn't help. It doesn't remove the fields. It also retains the typed values.

Answer (score 1):

UPD: you don't need to use `Vue.set`, try this instead:

`formSchema.splice(0, formSchema.length)`

Comment: Thanks for answering, will try that.